# How can I select text in a window in which text selection is disabled?

Tags: windows, select, text

How could I be able to select text in a window in which selecting text is disabled?

I've tried these solutions, but none succeeded:

1. GetWindowText
2. Copy error messages text to the clipboard via `Ctrl+C`

This is a type of a window from which I need to select text from:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Zrw.png

Answer (score 0):

There's a program called *GetWindowText* which allows you to do this. It's downloadable from [this](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/GetWindowText) location.

Comment: I've already tried it with no success to detect the text highlighted in the image!